# rsync with symlink on path

Tags: rsync, symlink

Say we have a path on our directory like:

```
a/b/c/d/e
```

where `c` is actually a symlink,

`a/b/c -> f`

And `f` contains `d/e`.

Then when I run `rsync -avzR`, without the `--copy-unsafe-links` flag, it will still copy this "unsafe" link.

Expected:

```
a/b/c->f
f/d/e
```

when I run `rsync -avzR a/b/c/d/e some_dir`.

Actual output:

```
a/b/c/d/e
```

How can I get the expected output in this way?

Comment: It's not clear to me how a/b/c relates to f or d/e. Can you elaborate please

Comment: Can you please show the full command you're running?  (You don't show how you're specifying the path(s) to copy)  Is "c" a relative or absolute symlink?

Comment: I can send a MVCE command next Monday. I'm out of town for now.

Answer (score 1):

Per [`man rsync`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/rsync/rsync.1.en.html) (my emphasis):

> **-R, --relative**
>
> Use relative paths. This means that the full path names specified on the command line are sent to the server rather than just the last parts of the filenames. [If] you used
>
> `rsync -avR /foo/bar/baz.c remote:/tmp/`
>
> then a file named /tmp/foo/bar/baz.c would be created on the remote machine, preserving its full path. These extra path elements are called **"implied directories"** (i.e. the "foo" and the "foo/bar" directories in the above example).
>
> Beginning  with  rsync  3.0.0, **rsync always sends these implied
>   directories as real directories in the file list, even if a path
>   element  is really a symlink on the sending side.**  This prevents
>   some really unexpected behaviors when copying the full path of a
>   file  that you didn’t realize had a symlink in its path.  If you
>   want to duplicate a server-side symlink, include both  the  sym‐
>   link via its path, and referent directory via its real path.  If
>   you’re dealing with an older rsync on the sending side, you  may
>   need to use the `--no-implied-dirs` option.

So, the behaviour you experienced is expected.

How to overcome this? I have not tested this, but I think a viable workaround would be along the lines:

```
mkdir -p some_dir/a/b
rsync -avz a/b/ some_dir/a/b  # Trailing slash after first 'b'
rsync -avz a/b/c/f some_dir   # No trailing slash after 'f'
```

I would also recommend reading the **SYMBOLIC LINKS** section of the `rsync` man page.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but unfortunately after running that I end up with the same result; the symlink is not respected.

Comment: @OneRaynyDay, I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate your behavior.  I've created a script that sets up a directory and then copies it.  It has a relative and an absolute symlink inside.  With the options that you show (`-avzR`), it shouldn't descend into either one, but copy the link as a link.

I assume that I've misinterpreted some aspect of what you're trying.  So you can add in to your question if you find what that is, or you can run this script and see if your behavior is different than I show.

Script:

```
#!/bin/sh
SRC=/tmp/syncsrc
DEST=/tmp/syncdest
rm -rf $SRC $DEST
mkdir -p $SRC/a/b
mkdir -p $SRC/f/d
touch $SRC/f/d/e
ln -s ../../f $SRC/a/b/c
ln -s $SRC/f $SRC/a/b/g
mkdir $DEST
rsync -avzRi $SRC/a $DEST
```

Output

```
sending incremental file list
cd+++++++++ /tmp/
cd+++++++++ /tmp/syncsrc/
cd+++++++++ /tmp/syncsrc/a/
cd+++++++++ /tmp/syncsrc/a/b/
cL+++++++++ /tmp/syncsrc/a/b/c -> ../../f
cL+++++++++ /tmp/syncsrc/a/b/g -> /tmp/syncsrc/f
```

And the destination is created with the symlinks inside

```
$ find /tmp/syncdest \( -type l -printf '%h/%f -> %l\n' \) -o -printf '%h/%f\n'
/tmp/syncdest
/tmp/syncdest/tmp
/tmp/syncdest/tmp/syncsrc
/tmp/syncdest/tmp/syncsrc/a
/tmp/syncdest/tmp/syncsrc/a/b
/tmp/syncdest/tmp/syncsrc/a/b/c -> ../../f
/tmp/syncdest/tmp/syncsrc/a/b/g -> /tmp/syncsrc/f
```